# Regex related to * and + in python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python. I didnt understand the behaviour of these program in python.

```
import re
sub="dear"
pat="[aeiou]+"
m=re.search(pat,sub)
print(m.group())
```

This prints "ea"

```
import re
sub="dear"
pat="[aeiou]*"
m=re.search(pat,sub)
print(m.group())
```

This doesnt prints anything.

I know + matches 1 or more occurences and * matches 0 or more occurrences. I am expecting it to print "ea" in both program.But it doesn't.

Why this happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This doesnt prints anything.

Not exactly. It prints an empty string which you just of course you didn't notice, as it's not visible. Try using this code instead:

```
l = re.findall(pat, sub)
print l
```

this will print:

```
['', 'ea', '', '']
```

---

**Why this behaviour?**

This is because when you use `*` quantifier - `[aeiou]*`, this regex pattern also matches an empty string before every non-matching string and also the empty string at the end. So, for your string `dear`, it matches like this:

```
*d*ea*r*  // * where the pattern matches.
```

All the `*'s` denote the position of your matches.

- `d` doesn't match the pattern. So match is the empty string before it.
- `ea` matches the pattern. So next match is `ea`.
- `r` doesn't match the pattern. So the match is empty string before `r`.
- The last empty string is the empty string after `r`.

Comment: @MSB. Just added the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Using `[aeiou]*`, the pattern match at the beginning. You can confirm that using [`MatchObject.start`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start):

```
>>> import re
>>> sub="dear"
>>> pat="[aeiou]*"
>>> m=re.search(pat,sub)
>>> m.start()
0
>>> m.end()
0
>>> m.group()
''
```

Answer (score 1):

`+` matches at least one of the character or group before it. `[aeiou]+` will thus match at least one of `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` or `u` (vowels).

The regex will look everywhere in the string to find the minimum 1 vowel it's looking for and does what you expect it to (it will relentlessly try to get the condition satisfied).

`*` however means at least 0, which also means it can match nothing. That said, when the regex engine starts to look for a match at the beginning of the string to be tested, it doesn't find a match, so that the `0` match condition is satisfied and this is the result that you obtain.

If you had used the string `ear`, note that you would have `ea` as match.